# ios path issue in app missing libidn-1.15.tar.gz

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, xcode6

I just downloaded this git app

https://github.com/funkyboy/Building-a-Jabber-client-for-iOS

I am trying to run the app. I am ios compelte newbie. I have it pulled up in my code but it gives me this error
[image]

I am not sure how to solve this issue. I am running xcode Version 6.1.1(6A2008a) How do I try debug this issue in ios?

I tried to do a search for the folder and this is what came up

[image]

After a little search I found this
https://github.com/funkyboy/Building-a-Jabber-client-for-iOS/issues/8

But it does not tell me where and how to add that file and framework?

Answer (score 1):

If you check [this link](https://github.com/funkyboy/Building-a-Jabber-client-for-iOS/issues/7) you will come to know that the owner of that project does not wish to provide an further support to users. 
`"You are own your own from here"` [taken from project's read me file] 
I guess you will have to do some research and hard-work if you wish to continue to use this project.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. What I did is just remove the libidn from Link Framework and Libraries, then add the library again.

To Remove: go to Build Phases->Link Framework and Libraries->Libidn

To Add Again: on Build Phases->Link Framework and Libraries->Click Plus Sign->Select Add Other and browse the location of libidn (XMPP->Vendor->Libidn->libidn.a)

Hope this helps.